# How to check if switch is ipv6 fully compatible

Tags: switch, ipv6

We will move to IPv6 in the next months and I have a lot of switches and routers and I want to discard IPv6 non-compatible or not fully compatible devices.

What kind of standar I will need to check in the specs from manufacturer?

I was reading and I found the standard 802.3, that is enought to say "ok, this is compatible"? or I will need to make another point in manual before discard it.

UPDATE: this is a small list of devices:

3COM
- 3C16471
- 3CR17254-91
- 3E 16793
- E4510-24G
CISCO
- SF100D-08
D-LINK
- DES-1005D
- DES-1024D
- DGS 3120-24TC-S
- DGS3024
- DGS-3100-48
- DGS3324
HEWLETT PACKAR
- HNGZA-HA0016
HEWLETT PACKARD
- 1410-24G
- 1810-24G
- 2530-24G
- 2530-48G
- V1910-48G
NETGEAR
- FS108
- JGS516PE
TP-LINK
- T2600G-28TS
- TL-SG1024

Comment: Hi and welcome to NE!  We hope you will become a contributing member of this community.  To better answer your question, please edit your question to include the models of routers and switches you have and their software versions.   Generally speaking, Layer 2 switches don't know or care if the layer 3 traffic is IPv4 or IPv6.  But the management interface may be an issue if you intend to manage your switches through IPv6.  Routers, on the other hand, do care.

Comment: Thanks... the list is huge... let me add some of them

Comment: Sadly, most of these devices are consumer-grade, which makes them off-topic on this forum.  You can ask about them on [su].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real beauty of separating the network stack into layers is that each layer is independent of the other layers.

IP (both IPv4 and IPv6), is a layer-3 protocol, and it really does not care what layer-1 or layer-2 protocols (ethernet, token ring, FDDI, frame relay, PPP, HDLC, ATM, Wi-Fi, etc.) carries it.

Ethernet, as a set of layer-1/2 protocols, really doesn't care about the payload of the ethernet frames. This allows ethernet to carry IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.

---

Having said that, there may be advanced switch features, which you may or may not be using, that do look at the layer-3 packet, but a switch performing standard layer-2 switching doesn't care about anything except the layer-2 frames, which could encapsulate any layer-3 protocol.

---

Based on the experience of adding IPv6 to an enterprise network, set up up a lab and test, Test, TEST. Vendors of both hardware and software will claim IPv6 compatibility, but that often means it doesn't crash when faced with IPv6, not that it is really IPv6 capable.

Answer (score 2):

For pure layer-2 switching, *any* switch is compatible with IPv6 - or rather IPv6 can be transported over any switched network. A layer-2 device like a switch doesn't see or care about higher-layer protocols.

If you need layer-3 functions on the switch (routing between ports or VLANs, filtering based on IP addresses, or similar) you'll need to check the device specifications. The same goes for the management interface (which doesn't usually hurt staying on IPv4 for now).

*Edit* after list was added:

Most of your switches are unmanaged ones. They don't make any difference between IPv4 and IPv6 at all. Nearly all of the managed switches are layer-2 only switches, they don't make a difference either, except for the management functions. At least the HPE 2530 series is IPv6 compatible for management and ACLs.

The only layer-3 switch I can make out is the V1910-48G which is IPv6-capable for routing and ACLs.